# How to use my store as Progressive Web App in Magento 2?

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, progressive-web-apps

I have a existing Magent02 store and I want to use PWA feature on it.

Comment: You can check the [implementation of the PWA in Magento](https://community.magento.com/t5/PWA-Theming-Layout-Design/Links-to-PWA-JavaScript-Framework-etc-blogs-add-yours-here/m-p/70548) forum. You will get a lot of resources from there. At the same time, you can visit [this post from SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193877/how-to-use-pwa-in-magento2).

Answer (score 3):

PWA is a philosophy and how you want to implement it is your own choice.

You will at least need a [serviceworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) and a [manifest.json](https://github.com/meanbee/magento2-webappmanifest), and the traffic should be over a secure network. You can read more about the implementation of PWA at the [Magento forum](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-PWA-Theming-Layout/Links-to-PWA-JavaScript-Framework-etc-blogs-add-yours-here/m-p/70548). Two of 
 the current implementations that you could use are the [Vue Storefront](https://www.vuestorefront.io/) and [Deity](https://deity.io/). Magento is creating [PWA studio](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Introducing-Magento-PWA-Studio/ba-p/74636) that you might want to wait for.